How to handle long running operations when interfacing with Kafka in Rust?
I'm writing a Rust application which reads some data from Kafka and archives it to disk.
The function which converts the data to the correct format, and then writes this data to disk  takes a long time to run in some cases. (Up to a couple of minutes.)
This causes the Kafka consumer to panic, because when it next polls for data it finds that it has been disconnected by the broker (default) 30 seconds timeout.
I seen, and solved, this problem before. However my previous solution was written in Python.
My solution was to spawn a seperate thread which continually polled the consumer after pausing it. This thread would watch for an event to fire. When that event fired, it would resume the consumer and exit. The main thread was responsible for launching this secondary thread, signalling the event, and joining the thread again.
I tried to implement this in Rust, but my code became a complete mess. I was juggling all kinds of stuff like objects contained inside of mutexes contained inside of Arc boxes, all while using scope to hack the release of mutex objects. What I had started to become unmanagable, and this is probably because I don't have a solid understanding of how to do multithreading in Rust. It's the kind of thing that's easy to do in C++, because there are no additional constraints imposed by the additional rules of the Rust compiler borrow checker.
Here's some example code. It's a single threaded implementation which will blow up when the process_message function is called. (If you run it you should find the consumer fails when this function exits, assuming you have not manually lengthened the default Kafka consumer poll timeout setting.)
use core::str;

use rdkafka::consumer::Consumer;
use rdkafka::Message;

fn process_message(message: &str) {
    println!("message: {message}");
    println!("sleep 60");
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(60));
    println!("wake");
}

fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {

    let config =
        rdkafka::config::ClientConfig::new()
        .set("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.239:9092")
        .set("client.id", "html_source_div_archiver.rust")
        .set("group.id", "html_source_div_archiver.rust")
        .set("enable.auto.commit", "false")
        .set("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
        .set("isolation.level", "read_committed")
        .to_owned();

    let consumer: rdkafka::consumer::BaseConsumer =
        config
        .create()
        .expect("invalid client configuration");

    let topic_html_source_div = "example_topic";
    let topics = [topic_html_source_div];
    consumer.subscribe(&topics).expect("failed to subscribe");

    loop {

        let poll_timeout = std::time::Duration::from_secs(10);
        let optional_message = consumer.poll(poll_timeout);

        match optional_message {
            Some(maybe_message) => {

                let message = maybe_message.expect("some message failure");

                let optional_payload = message.payload();
                match optional_payload {
                    Some(payload) => {

                        let message_str = str::from_utf8(payload).expect("invalid UTF-8");
                        process_message(message_str);

                        consumer
                            .commit_consumer_state(rdkafka::consumer::CommitMode::Sync)
                            .expect("failed to commit consumer state");
                    }

                    None => {
                        panic!("payload is None");
                    }
                }
            }

            None => {
                println!("waiting for messages");
            }
        }
    }
}

Below is some additional code which shows my Python solution to the problem.
As you can see, I have created a second function called consumer_poll_loop which does the following:

pause the consumer
loop forever, polling the paused consumer, while waiting for an event to be triggered
resume the consumer

use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;
use std::sync::atomic;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn consumer_poll_loop(
    event_thread_terminate: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    consumer: Arc<Mutex<rdkafka::consumer::BaseConsumer>>,
) {
    let consumer = consumer.lock().expect("failed to lock consumer mutex");

    let topic_partition_list = consumer.assignment().expect("consumer assignment failed");
    consumer.pause(&topic_partition_list).expect("consumer pause failed");

    loop {
        let poll_timeout = std::time::Duration::from_secs(10);
        let message = consumer.poll(poll_timeout);

        if message.is_some() {
            panic!("message is not None");
        }

        if event_thread_terminate.load(atomic::Ordering::Relaxed) {
            break;
        }
    }

    consumer.resume(&topic_partition_list).expect("consumer resume failed");
}

Note that there is no need to release the mutex in this function, because the consumer should not be accessed by the other thread while the thread managing this function is running.
I got as far as being able to launch this function, however I had to use a closure to do so, which I am not sure should be necessary.
I then started implementing the logic in the main function and ended up in a complete mess. This suggests to me I am doing something wrong.

I solved this problem using an AtomicBool for inter-thread signalling and Arc + Mutex to manage access to the consumer.
Without copying and pasting vast amounts of code...
This is my consumer poll loop.
fn consumer_poll_loop(
    consumer_poll_loop_terminate_flag: &std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool,
    consumer: std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<rdkafka::consumer::BaseConsumer>>,
) {
    let consumer = consumer.lock().expect("failed to lock consumer mutex");

    let topic_partition_list = consumer.assignment().expect("consumer assignment failed");
    consumer.pause(&topic_partition_list).expect("consumer pause failed");

    loop {
        let poll_timeout = std::time::Duration::from_secs(10);
        let message = consumer.poll(poll_timeout);

        if message.is_some() {
            panic!("message is not None");
        }

        if consumer_poll_loop_terminate_flag.load(std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed) {
            break;
        }
    }

    consumer.resume(&topic_partition_list).expect("consumer resume failed");
}

This is how I start the thread for the consumer poll loop. (The call to join may not be necessary.)
// start the consumer poll loop
let consumer_poll_loop_terminate_flag = std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool::new(false);
std::thread::scope(
    |scope| {
        let handle = scope.spawn(
            || {
                consumer_poll_loop(&consumer_poll_loop_terminate_flag, consumer_mutexed.clone());
            }
        );

        // long running function / logic goes here //
                
        // terminate the consumer poll loop
        consumer_poll_loop_terminate_flag.store(true, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed);

        handle.join().expect("failed to join thread");
    }
);

The "mutexed" consumer is created like this.
let consumer_mutexed = std::sync::Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(consumer));

I used a bit of a trick to get data out of the consumer. Here's a description of the problem you will run into if you do not use this "trick".

Data is returned from a consumer in the form of a message. By default, consumer.poll returns a borrowed message. This is no good, because the lifetime of the message is tied to the lifetime of the consumer. This means that if the consumer is inside a mutex, then the lifetime of the borrowed message data is tied to the duration for which the mutex is locked. This is no good if you need to share the consumer with another thread. (As in this example.)

To work around this, I used the detatch function to create an owned message out of a borrowed message. This appears to be essentially a clone operation.
In order to lock and then release the lock on the mutex, I used a bit of a "hack" with a closure.
let poll_timeout = std::time::Duration::from_secs(10);
let consumer_poll_lambda = || {
    let consumer = consumer_mutexed.lock().expect("failed to lock consumer mutex");
    let optional_message = consumer.poll(poll_timeout);
    match optional_message {
        Some(maybe_message) => {
            match maybe_message {
                Ok(message) => {
                    let message = message.detach();
                    return Some(Ok(message));
                }
                Err(error) => {
                    return Some(Err(error));
                }
            }
        }
        None => {
            return None
        }
    }
};
let optional_message = consumer_poll_lambda();

This closure actually does a bit of extra stuff in the form of error handling for convenience. It converts the Option<Result<>> structure into an Option.
Now the message is fully detached from the consumer. This solves the problem of not being able to pass the consumer to the thread function, but creates a new problem.
It is no longer possible to commit the consumer state from the main thread.
To work around this problem, I used an explicit commit style using the topic name, partition number and message offset.
Note that normally when calling commit on a consumer, the committed offset will be the message offset + 1. Here, I commit the message offset such that the same message will be consumed again if the process dies.
// commit current message offset such that current message will be
// consumed again on failure of process
let topic = message.topic();
let partition = message.partition();
let offset = rdkafka::Offset::from_raw(message.offset());
topic_partition_list
    .add_partition_offset(topic, partition, offset)
    .expect("failed to add partition offset to topic partition list");

consumer_mutexed
    .lock()
    .expect("failed to lock consumer mutex")
    .commit(&topic_partition_list, rdkafka::consumer::CommitMode::Sync)
    .expect("commit failed");

Normally, you would do this instead:
let topic = message.topic();
let partition = message.partition();
let offset = rdkafka::Offset::from_raw(message.offset()) + 1; // [!] Note + 1 here
topic_partition_list
    .add_partition_offset(topic, partition, offset)
    .expect("failed to add partition offset to topic partition list");

// commit


First, you will need some way to pass messages between threads. A common choice is crossbeam::channel.
Next, you can likely avoid the need for Arc/Mutex by using std::thread::scope() to spawn the other thread. Objects created before the call to scope() can be used freely without Arc. In other words, Arc<BaseConsumer> can simply become &BaseConsumer. I'd probably recommend something roughly like:
let consumer = ...; // Create and configure up the consumer
let (message_sender, message_receiver) = crossbeam::channel::unbounded(); // Create the message channel

std::thread::scope(|s| {
    // Spawn the helper thread
    s.spawn(move || {
        // consumer_poll_loop() should process new messages and send them
        // to the main thread via `message_sender.send()`.
        consumer_poll_loop(&consumer, message_sender);
    });

    // Receive new messages from the helper thread
    for message in message_receiver.iter() {
        // Write the message to disk...
    }

    // At this point, once the closure finishes, `std::thread::scope()` will
    // automatically wait for all child threads to cleanly finish.
});

Just for completeness, I'll note that if you want to avoid the need for event_thread_terminate, you would probably need a very complicated solution involving an async stream-based consumer, an async runtime like tokio, a OnceCell for the terminate message, and then a call to tokio::select!() to simultaneously listen for either a Kafka message or a terminate message. That would probably be overengineered, and I think your current approach is simpler and sufficient.
Finally, I'll note that if you find your disk I/O thread is too slow to keep up and decide you need multiple threads disk I/O, it may make more sense to flip things around: the main thread processes new messages, and several helper threads work on disk I/O. In that case, you can spawn several helper threads using something like for _ in 0..8 { s.spawn(...) }.
